# How to verify the position of the web page element

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I would like to know if there is any way to verify that a specific elment of a web page is in a given position. 
For instance, suppose you have a requirement stating:
"The lamp button shall appear on the upper left side corner of the web page".
How can I verify that the button is in the right position automatically? 
Firstly, I should ask the requirements engineer to translate the left position in coordinate and since I have been working with Selenium 2.0 JAVA API, I can use
the method "getLocation" of the element. Is the only way to verify the element position.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation%28%29

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to verify the location of an element.

`getLocation()` verifies the absolute location of an element.  I don't recommend this, it can change all the time depending on loading speeds and the size of the window.

`getCssValue()` can, to an extent, verify the relative location of an element.  Most modern websites do their layout via CSS. You can do a  `getCssValue("display")` which might return `block`,`grid`, or other layouts.  You can check the margin, border, or padding.

However, the above solution is also brittle, because a site can change their layout quite frequently.  It also requires the developer of the selenium code to know quite a lot about CSS.  Finally, it isn't fail-proof.  I can check for 20 different things, and still a single change in the CSS can completely change the position of the element.